# Compiling Festival on MingW32

Tags: c++, mingw, festival

I'm trying to compile [Festival](http://festvox.org/festival/downloads.html) on MingW32, so I can have a Windows binary.  I couldn't find the Windows binary on their site.  Anyone have one they can post?

If not, here's what I have so far.  I did the ./configure and make for it and have the following message:

```
$ make
config/config:43: ../speech_tools/config/config: No such file or directory
```

So, I downloaded the speech_tools tar ball and got.  Did the ./configure and make to get:

```
$ make
config/config:156: config/systems/ix86_unknown.mak: No such file or directory
../config/config:156: ../config/systems/ix86_unknown.mak: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `../config/systems/ix86_unknown.mak'.  Stop.
config/rules/modules.mak:133: config/modincludes.inc: No such file or directory
make --no-print-directory -C ./config MADE_FROM_ABOVE=1  MODINCLUDES=1 INCLUDE_EVERYTHING='' modincludes.inc 
../config/config:156: ../config/systems/ix86_unknown.mak: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `../config/systems/ix86_unknown.mak'.  Stop.
make: *** [config/modincludes.inc] Error 2
```

So, I copied config/systems/ix86_CYGWIN32.mak to ix86_unknown.mak and tried again.  Now I get this message:

```
g++ -c -fno-implicit-templates -O3 -Wall -Wno-non-template-friend -Wno-deprecated -DSUPPORT_EDITLINE -I../include slib.cc
In file included from slib.cc:85:
../include/EST_unix.h:53:25: sys/wait.h: No such file or directory
../include/EST_unix.h:54:29: sys/resource.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../include/EST_String.h:50,
                 from ../include/siod.h:17,
                 from slib.cc:88:
../include/EST_iostream.h:54:26: strstream.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../include/EST_TList.h:50,
                 from ../include/EST_string_aux.h:43,
                 from ../include/siod.h:18,
                 from slib.cc:88:
```

Where do I get sys/wait.h, sys/resource.h and strstream.h?  I'd rather not have to try this whole bit in Cygwin and carry around those annoying DLL's.  Any advice?

Comment: The link I posted below to the binaries also has a link to how to compile on Windows. I don't think it's possible without using Visual Studio (which is free to download, btw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows binaries are available [here](http://e-guidedog.sourceforge.net/download.php)

Comment: It worked just fine.  Hopefully, I don't need to make any changes to the festival code itself.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get further with a full cygwin install instead of just mingwin, but I can't promise success.

Comment: I caved and tried Cygwin.  No go.  It still needs strstream.h.

Comment: I couldn't even get it to compile on a pure Linux system, much less an emulated one. I have reason to believe it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I run Ubuntu and remember having Festival available in the Synaptics repository, implying I just had to double click the name, and the thing installed itself with all its dependencies.
If all else fails, you might want to run a VM with ubuntu or dual boot.

Comment: Note: the version on Synaptics might not be the latest